# POST data not being received from iPhone

Tags: php, ios, mysql, iphone, http-post

I've got an iPhone App that is supposed to send POST data to my server to register the device in a MySQL database so we can send notifications etc... to it. It sends it's unique identifier, device name, token, and a few other small things like passwords and usernames as a POST request to our server. The problem is that sometimes the server doesn't receive the data. And by this I mean, its not just receiving blank values for the POST inputs but, its not receiving ANY post data at all. I am logging all POST inputs to my server into some log files and when the script that relies on the POST data from the device fails (detects no data) I notice that its because NO POST data was sent. Is this a problem on the server, like refusing data or something or does this have to be on the client's side? What could be causing this?

iPhone Code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"deviceIdentifier=%@&deviceToken=%@",deviceIdentifier,deviceToken]; 
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/RegisterScript.php"]]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[request setValue:@"MyApp-V1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData]; 
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which is a great framework for communicating over http.  It will handle the communication asynchronous so you won't risk the app being stopped by the iPhone OS if the communication takes to long time. There are also methods to easier create the form data that is to be sent.